# Keyboard shortcut for "parent directory" in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse-gestures

I have recently transitioned from various mouse gesture browser extensions to a desktop-based mouse gesture utility ([Easystroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki) on Linux; the Windows equivalent would be [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) - I think). The only thing I'm missing now is a gesture for "navigate to the parent directory" or "navigate one level up" or something like that. All commonly used mouse gesture extensions offer something like this, but to make it work with a desktop-based program, I need to emulate a key press.

Do Chrome/Chromium or Firefox have any keyboard shortcuts for that? If not... any idea how I could emulate that?

Comment: What do you mean by directory? Browsers don't normally display directories.

Comment: I mean going up one level in the URL path. For example, `http://example.com/foo/bar.html` would have `http://example.com/foo/` as parent, and then `http://example.com/`. By the way, browsers can display directories using the `file://` pseudo-protocol, where the same semantics would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think that such keyboard shortcut exists. The reason being that absolutely most modern sites will not let you just run back and forth like that... you will simply get access denied error response. It still could make some sense when you actually ftp using the browser. Now the "parent key" actually may help alot. I know that this isn't the kind of help you require but well :)

Oh wow! I think i found what you need for Chrome:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/navigup/eigojmmlmgigbldiclbpibmjnlbdpiaa
```

And similar one for Firefox but very old...

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/go-up/
```

I still don't know where it could be useful but seems like there is a demand for it :)

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I ended up using the "Uppity" extension for Firefox and "NavigUp" for Chrome, which both use Alt+Up as shortcuts. About its usefulness, you'd be surprised how many sites do support this kind of navigation (as they should!). Examples: GitHub, Wikipedia,... any directory sites. I use this all the time. Give it a try :)

Comment: Indeed. Another lesson learned and i shouldn't have judged so quickly on this. Will most likely start using it myself. So we both profit here. Thanks!